# ROS Python Code to select a Map Cell in a SLAM system

Tags: python, ros, robotics, slam

I am having trouble with this part of code for a robotics challenge for SLAM. The function can be found below and it is supposed to execute like this:

1. Get all the map cells that is either empty(0) or unoccupied(1)
2. Pick a cell and scan around the cells to determine if it is something good. If a score of 5 is summed up, it is a "good" point.
3. Go to that cell via a function that sends the message

However, on my RVIZ screen when I execute this code, the turtlebot will just keep spinning instead of moving as you can see here:

[image: 1]

```
def get_valid_cells(self, height, gridmap, width):
        # Get Number of Explored Cells
        cells_explored = np.count_nonzero(gridmap > -1)
        rospy.loginfo("Cells Explored %i", cells_explored)

        # Create an Array with Cells to Pick
        cells = 0
        score = 0
        cells_to_pick = np.zeros((cells_explored, 2))
        for y in xrange(0, height):
            for x in xrange(0, width):
                idx = x + y * width
                if gridmap[idx] > -1:
                    for y2 in xrange(y-1, y+2):
                        for x2 in xrange(x-1, x+2):
                            if gridmap[idx] > -1:
                                score =+ score
                                if score > 5:
                                    cells_to_pick[cells][0] = x2
                                    cells_to_pick[cells][1] = y2
                                    cells = cells + 1
        return cells_to_pick
```

I have tried changing the code but I don't understand it enough to modify it to display a pose goal on the screen. Please help.

Comment: this looks one part of some code (a method of a class). If you do not yourself understand that code how can you be sure the errors do not come from one of the other methods ?    in order for users to help please provide this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This code will never read a score larger than 0 since it gets initialized with 0 and you alway add its value to itself. Also, `score =+ score` should be `score += score`. Typo? Furthermore, I wonder why you pass the parameters width, gridmap, height in that particular order. Might be a mistake as well? Finally, you don't handle edge cases in that code (surrounding of border pixels). Hence, I agree with D.L